# Angular/RxJS multiple subscriptions to http service observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to have multiple angular components subscribe to a single http service. he flow of events is: User clicks button in test-data.component.html > test-data.service makes POST request > subscription in test-data.component receives data AND parent.component.ts receives data. The issue is that parent.component.ts never recieves that new data from the POST. Do I need to notify the parent.component that changes happened in the service provider?  Here are the relevant parts of the application:

parent.component.html

```
<div>  
 <app-test-data></app-test-data>
</div>
```

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-short-form',
 templateUrl: './short-form.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./short-form.scss'],
 providers:[ShortFormService, TestDataService]
})

constructor(
 private testDataService: TestDataService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {   
 this.testDataService.getTestData()
  .subscribe(
    (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      switch (event.type) {
        case HttpEventType.Response:
          console.log(' Done!', event.body);
      }
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        console.log("Client-side error occured.");
      } else {
        console.log("Server-side error occured.");
      }
    }
  )
```

}

test-data.component.html

```
<button m(click)="getTestData($event)" >Populate w/ match</button>
```

test-data.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-data',
  templateUrl: './test-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-data.component.scss'],
  providers: [TestDataService]

})
constructor(
 private testDataService: TestDataService,
) { }

getTestData(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 this.testDataService.getTestData()
 .subscribe(     
  (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    switch (event.type) {
      case HttpEventType.Response:
        console.log(' Done!', event.body);          
    }
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      console.log("Client-side error occured.");
    } else {`enter code here`
      console.log("Server-side error occured.");
    }
  }
)
}
```

test-data.service.ts

```
constructor(
 private http:HttpClient
) { }

getTestData(): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.testDataUrl, {
    reportProgress: true,
  });
var result = this.http.request(req).share();
return result
```

Comment: you need to have a varaible in that service like a `behavioursubject ` or `replaysubject` that will notify the parent component. This is a classic case for you to use shared services to avoid event spaghetti or use ngrx .
ngrx [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx) shared services [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Subject or BehaviourSubject and make your compometes subscribe to it.
You can find more about these topic in this link: 
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: Excellent resource in your link! I got it working based on the example given. What is the purpose of having the messaging.service separate? Reusability? My initial approach was trying to bake the messaging.service functionality into my test-data.service

Comment: Thank you, the purpose of using services in angular is separation of concerns and reusability. you do not need to apply the message service in your code, just understand the way Subject works and implemented in your test-data.service.